# Can an Error 429 be related to CSS?

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-429

I recently received this error when trying to run an address on a website I am working on, but didn't build. I am fairly new to HTTP errors, so my question is about whether CSS can cause the 429 error in general, as opposed to it being a problem with a specific web platform.

> HTTP response body: 429 Too many requests body { padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */ } Error 429 Too many requests

The body tag does have quite a lot of classes listed. Based on the error message, is the number of classes, as listed below, a possible source of the error, or are they totally unrelated.

```
<body class="wp-admin wp-core-ui no-js  backwpup_page_backwpupjobs auto-fold admin-bar branch-4-3 version-4-3-1 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us no-customize-support no-svg">
```

Comment: It depends on if the CSS file is making requests to the server for things like background images.

Comment: No, that is most likely completely unrelated.